# Fetching data from a webpage when a button is pressed in scala js

Tags: scala.js

I want to fetch the data from some text boxes which I've in a form on my web page in scala js. I've tried it using HTML'` onclick event like :

```
<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="TutorialApp().fun()">Submit</button>
```

and I've created a function in my TutorialApp object like :

```
object TutorialApp extends JSApp {

@JSExport
def main(): Unit = {
   ..... 
}

def fun():Unit = {
 println("Button is clicked")
}
```

But it is showing error that TutorialApp().fun() is not a function. What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, you might want to register the onclick handlers in your code:

```
import org.scalajs.dom

def main(): Unit = {
  dom.document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", fun _)
}
```

The advantage is that you do not need to export `fun` and you get compile time name safety (i.e. if you rename `fun`, the compiler will tell you if you forgot to rename it somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

It worked by adding @JSExport before fun(). I didn't notice that.